# How to set custom interval labels on Primefaces barchart

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bar-chart, jqplot, label

I am having some difficulty understanding how to customize data labels for axes in a PF bar chart. I want to populate the actual data points / intervals with variables other than what is on the series. Basically I want more control and flexibility of how to label axes in PF charts. For example, I have the following the bar chart:

```
public void barChartMod() {

    ChartSeries rigSeries = new ChartSeries();
    List<Rigtest> bList = rigFacade.findAll();        
    Map<Object, Number> barMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Object, String> tickMap= new HashMap<>();
    for (Rigtest t : bList) {
        barMap.put(t.getRigtestid(), t.getRignum());
    }

    barModel = new BarChartModel();

    rigSeries.setData(barMap);
    barModel.addSeries(rigSeries);
    barModel.setSeriesColors("FF0000");
    barModel.setShowPointLabels(true);
    Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);

}
```

The x axis is basically chart series which takes values from a map consisting of a primary key and number of rigs from a table called Rigtest. The table has the following schema:

RigtestId(PK Int), Country(foreign key entity to Country table), Rignum (int - number of rigs)

I want the x axis to be lebeled with country names. If I simply include the country names in the Map it results in duplicate values and will also show values for the unique country names. I would like to show values for each record in the series.

This can be achieved if I use the primary key to iterate through each value in the series (as above). This is an acceptable way to obtain the values, but  I need a way to label each point on the x-axis with names of the country instead of just the numbers.

Currently my bar chart looks like this:

[image]

This graph is used to compare numbers of different countries during a date range specified by a user query. The x axis are labels which get their values from the unique primary key (Rigestid). Instead of using the PK for the x axis label, I want to use country names and produce a graph like this:

[image]

In the above graph, CountryName belongs to the Country entity pertaining to each PK and should be obtained by looping through an instance of the Country entity, for example:

```
Map<Object, String> tickMap= new HashMap<>();

for(Rigtest b: bList) {
        tickMap.put(b.getRigtestid(), b.getCountry().getCountryname());
    }
```

If I simply try to put the county names instead of the primary keys, I will get 4 instead of 6 bars (since the duplicated country names will be ignored). Therefore, if I stick to the primary key as a way of obtaining the values for x axis, I need a way of populating the labels with country names.

The PF documentation and most of the online material only says how to add labels to the axis, but not how to customize individual points of the axes in PF charts. I also looked at jqplot. This seems to deal with manually hardcoding axis labels, but I can't find any guide on how to populate interval points dynamically from a database.

Basically I'm simply trying to label the x axis with something other than the mapping used to obtain its values, but included in the same underlying data schema. I'm sure there is a simple way to achieve this and I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PrimeFaces usea jqplot. Search there. If you find something, try to implement it with the extender functionality

Comment: Btw have you seen the other answer on your other post? Does that help? It uses country names. (It is a better solution than yours I think)

Comment: I tried it but it also results in outputting only 2 values and seems to make no difference to using Maps. If I"m missing something please let me know otherwise it looks like there is no avoiding jq plot as it offers more flexibility. Still I would rather achieve something simple like customizing axes labels through raw Primefaces if possible. So i'm open to learn if this other answer is really what I need but i'm implementing it wrong. Many thanks for your input!

Comment: The first image here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml is,what you want right? Basic stuff. If not, create an image with what you want.

Comment: This is where one of the causes of you problem is. _"Seems like I am forced to use the primary key to iterate through each and every value in the series. "_ My comment in the othe postsaid you were putting multiple identical keys in a hashmap. It nowhere stated that you should use primary keys.

Comment: Taje a goooood look in the PF showcase how to use series.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question with more details and images. Please let me know if this clearer now. Using primary keys seemed to be the only way for me to get all six records because the entry in the table involves identical country names for different dates. I will look at the PF showcases again, but i don't see any similar example and nothing that deals with customizing axis labeling. Also on JQPlot the labeling scripts are mostly hardcoded. Maybe it's possible to adapt this labeling to obtain value dynamically but it's not clear how to achieve that.

Comment: These are weird graphs... What is the difference between the two 'Netherlands' or two 'France' bars? No one can know. Are you sure there is not some kind of grouping? Or some differentiation (male/femal/...).

Comment: I agree. They are not conventional graphs.  They are time series occurrences in a given date range. So the differentiator is the date. Maybe a line chart is more appropriate but it is preferable if I can achieve this with a bar chart. This is what the end user is requesting. In any case I would expect a graphing library to be able to deal with these situations. I'm hopeful that there is a way to achieve the above but neither the vanilla Primefaces nor the jqplot seems to have any immediate answers. Please let me know if I need to provide any further information. Thanks

Comment: With a line chart you have the same problem. Why not check if the hashmap already contains the key and if so, add '-#<number>'  as a postfix. And if -#1 (or -1) also exists, try -#2 etc. Or if you can group them by date, us the date as a series and in there put the countries. Countries get different colors then, so easy to distinguish (just like the example I referred to) Help the customer (they often do not know what is all possible). And considering jqplot does not even have something, that is an indication how uncommon (weird) it is.

Comment: What you can also try is to give the Country class you already seem to have a toString() that returns the countryName, but in the equals and compareTo, make sure the primary key is used to. Then they are different for the hashMap, no duplicates but in the chart the label will be the same, the country name.

Comment: Great suggestions which I will try. It sounds like the solution is in implementing good Java code rather than the jqplot route. Good news  since I'm more comfortable with Java. Maybe iI also need good underlying chart 'logic to begin with'.  I still can't help thinking that a scripting library like jqplot should be able to handle ALL customizations. Java will be my first attempt but I still can't find good documentation to teach me how to implement jqplot with PF in a dynamic environment. Maybe this is another question.